# Limiting a string to alphabetical letters, C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, while-loop, readline

I have made the following code:

```
string fname;
Console.WriteLine("Input  employee first name:");
fname = Console.ReadLine();
```

The idea is to insert a while loop (with an "if" in it) to limit the input from the console to alphabetical letters only. However, using Tryparse doesn't work since it parses strings to ints. I would be grateful to receive suggestions on how to resolve this issue by "Tryparsing" strings to strings.

Comment: Which language should that be? And are you sure you want to ban names like `Céline`? Aside form japanese/chinese/korean names for example... My advice: Allow the use of any damn name someone could invent, you really don't want the frustration of nonsensical arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: The idea is not to let someone input something like:
Steve1242353. And the language is c#, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: So, add tag C#, and explain why you want to do that. What do you really want to accomplish this way?

Comment: This should be simple enough for a basic regex.

Comment: Obligatory link: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments on your question, a RegEx would probably be the simplest way to evaluate the input

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("yourtexthere", "^[a-zA-Z]{1,25}$").Success) {
    // it matches                
}
```

That should give you a good idea of how to accomplish it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Console.Write("Input  employee first name: ");
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.KeyChar == '\r')
            break;

        if (char.IsLetter(key.KeyChar))
        {
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            s.Append(key.KeyChar);
        }
    } while (true);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine( "You typed " + s.ToString());
```